# Hide buttons overlay (e.g. 5 second burst) on Google Camera

Tags: buttons, google-camera

I have been getting overlays as such on my Nexus 5, Nexus 6 and now my Nexus 6P - haven't noticed exactly when they start to appear and have yet to find a way to disable them - please take a look at the following image:

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

If you look at the upper right, you should notice a few buttons on the viewfinder. It used to be just two, now I have three after the camera app updated. They were not there when I initially got any of my Nexus devices but shortly presented themselves afterwards.

I do use my Nexus devices for debugging so I have disabled debug mode to see if there was any connection, but this does not seem to be the case.

Is there sort sort of hidden button I must press (ex; how the developer menu is activated) in order to hide these buttons once again?

Comment: The buttons in the upper-right corner seem to be the flash indicator, HDR mode, and self-timer.  To what buttons are you referring?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recently had the same issue with my 6P, running 6.0.1 and the latest Google Camera version 3.1.021. It turned out to be a result of having the **Screenwise Trends Panel** app installed on all my phones. Enabling it in **Accessibility Services** causes the buttons to show up. From my searching there is no real solution other than to **disable the Accessibility Service toggle for Screenwise. Then the buttons go away.**

Comment: AH! Wow, seriously! Yep, I make use of Screenwise as well for some cheap Google Play funds - guess I can uninstall it on my main device at least.

Answer (score 3):

The buttons overlay (i.e. <kbd>Z-</kbd>, <kbd>Z+</kbd>, and <kbd>5 SECOND BURST</kbd>) are part of Android's accessibility feature, TalkBack. Refer to [Google Camera Help - Use TalkBack with Google Camera](https://support.google.com/googlecamera/?hl=en#6149231).

To hide the buttons, you need to turn off TalkBack feature on **Android Settings - Accessibility - TalkBack - tap to toggle off**.

**Note**: the buttons are integrated to the TalkBack feature, so there's no way to hide the buttons without turning TalkBack feature.

Comment: This is neat, but TalkBack is off on my device.
Turning it on then back off, does not get rid of the buttons either.

Comment: @avluis I see... this is the only clue I have tested and proven on my device, but it seems there's something more in your case... I'll try to experiment with it again, but I can't promise the fix... Edit: try to switch off any Accessibility option and see if it helps. Just now when I tested Switch Access accessibility, the buttons also appeared.

Answer (score 3):

I too had this menu enabled today. Later I found that, I was playing around with accessibility settings today. I've (accidentally) enabled "Switch access", so I got this menu in camera app.

Now after disabling the Switch access, this menu was gone in camera.